# Can the C++ compiler introduce vector.reserve calls?

Tags: c++, stdvector

Occasionally I see code like

```
std::vector x;
x.reserve(y.size());
for (auto a : y) {
  ...
  x.push_back(...);
}
```

But I don't like writing `reserve` because it's extra clutter and feels like a micro-optimization, especially when I know `y.size()` will be small.

That makes me wonder: does the compiler introduce such reserve calls if they're not present in the code? It'd have to treat `std::vector` specially, sure, but approximately everyone uses it so that wouldn't be so bad. Are there any rules that'd prohibit the compiler from doing this?

**Update:** I meant specifically: in this case it's obvious that `x` will have `y.size` elements -- could/do compilers reserve that up-front?

**Update 2:** Rewrote body of for-loop in examples to avoid suggestions like `std::transform`. This is a made-up example to illustrate a case where a compiler can predict the final size of a `std::vector`. I don't care particularly for this specific example.

Comment: The `std::vector` itself will call `reserve` when it needs to grow.  The only micro-optimization point to calling `reserve` *a priori* is because you know something that can make `std::vector` not need to resize during the operation, to mitigate possibly multiple possibly expensive allocation and copy operations.

Comment: I think it is legal for compilers to do this kind of optimization. I doubt one does that though.

Comment: I suggest to create a function (`transform`) to do it only once. ranges would be fine to `auto x  = y | ranges::transform([](auto &){ return Process(a); }) | ranges::to_vector;`.

Comment: Probably not as there could be an observable difference if the vector's capacity differed between a reserve call and natural growth of the vector.  eg reserve 100 would give a capacity of 100, but natural growth (using doubling) would give a capacity of 128.  There would also be an observable difference in the number of times each element was moved or copied.

Comment: I regularly call `reserve()` when I know already that I have an object which will certainly cause one or more allocations later on. As a programmer, I should know more about my code then the compiler. ;)

Comment: @RichardCritten the exact overcapacity of a vector is implementation defined.

Comment: @Caleth In theory, yes. But in practice, a compiler just compiles the source code of some standard library implementation (such as libstdc++ or libc++) and it would need to change its observable behavior. I don't say it's not possible, just don't think any compiler would do that.

Comment: @DanielLangr, that sounds like it could be the solution. I was thinking: the compiler might reserve up-front, essentially moving all the resizes to before the push_backs. That seems like it would be allowed by the as-if rule, if not always then at least for trivially movable types. But indeed: it may have to reserve the capacity the vector would've ended up with after `y.size()` push_backs, and not simply `y.size()`.

Answer (score 4):

> Can the C++ compiler introduce vector.reserve calls?

It won't.

> it's extra clutter

You need to weigh the cost of one line of "clutter" versus the benefits.

> and feels like a micro-optimization.

Good. It *is* a micro-optimisation.

---

If `y` is  a random access container or range, then you don't need to reserve if you use an iterator or range algorithm instead of a bare loop. For example:

```
auto t = std::ranges::transform_view(y, Process);
x.assign(std::begin(t), std::end(t));
```

If `y` is not a random access container / range, then using `reserve` is still beneficial.

Comment: Care to elaborate on "it won't"? That was (intended to be) the main point of my question.

Comment: @Pieter-PaulKramer The standard doesn't explicitly specify the capacity of a vector in most cases, and if the compiler can prove that you never observe the capacity, then it would be allowed to set it to be whatever is optimal. But it's generally too difficult to prove that, and compilers don't do such optimisations in practice.

Comment: Your comment seems to "contradict" your answer, it can but it won't.

Comment: Even if we observe capacity, as its value is implementation specific, it might be allowed to use any value. As printing timing of a function doesn't disallow optimization.

Comment: current compiler mostly(there are some execptions) treat the standard library as any other code. compiler are usually not "aware" of implementation defined or UB of the standard library.

Comment: @Jarod42 that we could observe it and find it different (even if implementation specific) would disallow the optimisation under the as-if-rule - as we can observe a difference between the optimised and non-optimised program

Comment: @RichardCritten: Not sure if compiler has to state the value (might depend between unspecified (as order for `f(g(), h())` where `h()` might be called before or after `g()` even for successive call of that `f`), or implementation defined (I think compiler has to document the behavior)). But as I said `std::cout << (time_of([](){ some_function(); }) < 1s : "fast" : "slow");` might print different result depending of optimization.